# Greece Schengen Visa queries for UK resident

Tags: proof-provenance-of-funds, uk-residents, schengen-visas

I'm applying for a short stay tourist visa (trip is for 8 days) for me and my wife.

My questions as follow:

1) The trip is all inclusive (paid in full), do I still need to have proof of funds? 
If yes, 
* I have an account with Bank A with less than £200 as balance but salary flows in every month and a savings account with same Bank holding amount for at-least £650 balance every month from past 4-5 months 
* I have a Bank B account holding £660+ balance from December 28 (applying on 13th March)
* Also having a credit card with £4000 limit (which I bring it back to ZERO balance every month)

Can I use all of them together? or I can use one of them? 3 months statements are evident enough to get visa?

2) My wife is Dependent according to my UK Visa, do we need to produce any document about her employment? (she is self employed though)

3) What documents are must for Dependent?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance for all your replies.

Answer (score 4):

If you have already paid for an all-inclusive trip, then that should serve for proving that you have the *means* to support yourself during the trip and leave afterwards.

However, this is only one of the things bank statements are supposed to document.

The other purpose of asking for bank statement is to *document your economic situation in your country of residence* such that the consulate can verify that (a) it makes sense for you to spend such-and-such an amount on a vacation trip, and (b) you have ties to your country of residence that will motivate you to leave the Schengen area rather than overstay as an undocumented immigrant.

So you will still need bank statements. The precise amount of money you have is not particularly important in your situation; what IS important is that the statements paint a picture of a stable economy with a reliable income that you would not want to jeopardize in favor of life as an illegal immigrant.

Your spouse and you can rely on the same financial documentation if you share a single household economy.  If she has bank accounts of her own, you should document both sides of the economy, with whatever you can get for her self-employment (business registration, tax papers or the like).

See Gayot Fow's excellent answer [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab), which is also on point for what Schengen consulates look for, in broad strokes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will definitely read that.

However my doubt is that for eg; if i go with the proposed amount per head per day as £40 x 8 = £320 Which would make £640 for both of us.

Do I need to have that substantial amount in my account for 3 months period or it doesn't matter for how many months/days as long as I have £640 as balance on my statement before going for visa interview??

Thanks

Comment: @vb: Those guideline amounts is for documenting means-of-subsistence, which you're doing in a different way by having bought an everything-included package trip. So they're not relevant in your situation.

Comment: I thought so, but its better get clarified :)

Thanks a lot for answering and have a nice day

Comment: @HenningMakholm why don't you add your comment to your answer; it's a very useful nugget +1.